# How do you use ShouldThrow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, assertions

I feel like it should be

```
Should.Throw<ArgumentNullException>(module.Execute(badArgument));
```

But when I try that there's no Throw method on the Should class or namespace.

There is however a couple methods, but when I call ShouldThrow

```
Should.ActionAssertionExtensions
    .ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>(() => module.Execute(badArgument));
```

it says it is an ambiguous call because there are two ShouldThrow method signatures

```
void ShouldThrow<TException>(this Should.Core.Assertions.Assert.ThrowsDelegate)    
void ShouldThrow<TException>(this System.Action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `should` be using:

```
Action action = () => module.Execute(badArgument);    
action.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
```

These are extension methods that are called on the objects being asserted on.